# How can I split MongoDB cursor iteration into multiple loops in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, python-asyncio

I am new to MongoDB and `pymongo`. I have a MongoDB collection which I connect to using `pymongo`. The average document size is about 80 kb and the total collection size is about 500 mb. The collection has about 7000 documents and it takes about 40 seconds to loop over it using:

```py
data = collection.find({})
for document in data:
    pass
```

This is a bit too long for my case as I need it always to be below 30 seconds for any collection size.

I was wondering if I could split the iteration into multiple loops and then use the `asyncio` library of Python so the loops can run at the same time. For example, I could split the cursor into 4 sub groups, i.e. from 0 to data.length/4, data.length/4 to data.length/4 * 2 etc. then loop through each group at the same time to reduce time.

I also cannot use `list(data)` because that would save the documents in memory and my RAM is limited.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the collection?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts I need to get some calculate some values using the document fields. I didn't put that in the question because I don't think it's necessary for my case.

Comment: Rather than looping through every document in Python, you might be able to calculate what you need in a single database query which would be a lot faster. What calculation are you trying to do?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts I am taking a certain field from each document, multiplying it by a number, then pushing that document to a list.

Comment: In that case it may be easier to use the [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) or [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) aggregation pipeline stage with the [$multiply](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/#multiply-aggregation) operator to do the work for you.

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts Okay I'll look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the standard library multiprocessing module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

You can split the work across processes and get a performance boost.

Comment: Okay but I am not quite sure how to split the MongoDB `Collection` into smaller groups.

Comment: Read the documentation. There a function called Pool.map which will handle splitting up an iterable across multiple processes. So you wouldn't have to worry about chunking it yourself.

Comment: Okay I'll look at that. Thanks.